# Can recurring tasks in org-agenda have a time block?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I want to schedule a task every day for the next four days from 9:15am to 10:45am. My `org` file is

```
#+Title: My Agenda

* Exercise
** Elliptical Workout
   <2016-12-28 Wed 09:15-10:45>--<2016-12-31 Sat>
```

My agenda exports as

```
Week-agenda (W52):
Monday     26 December 2016 W52
Tuesday    27 December 2016
Wednesday  28 December 2016
  tasks:       9:15am-10:45am (1/4):  Elliptical Workout
Thursday   29 December 2016
  tasks:      (2/4):  Elliptical Workout
Friday     30 December 2016
  tasks:      (3/4):  Elliptical Workout
Saturday   31 December 2016
  tasks:      (4/4):  Elliptical Workout
Sunday      1 January 2017
```

Only the first date has the `9:15am-10:45am` timeframe. Can this be altered?